# Not see data on the textarea

Tags: javascript, html

not see data on the textarea

`creatDocument.php`

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript">

         function insertFormulationToTextErea(string){
            document.getElementById("argumentId").value = string;
         }

      </script>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>

<textarea name="argument" id="argumentId" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['formulation']))
   $formulation = $_REQUEST['formulation'];
else $formulation = "No data receive";

$formulation = base64_decode($formulation);

echo "<script>insertFormulationToTextErea('$formulation')

</script>";

echo $formulation;

?>
   </body>
</html>
```

`$formulation` is the string parameter that received from another php page with `POST` method.
When I use with `echo` I see the string value, when I try to insert `$formulation` to textarea, the textarea is empty.

When I use with `GET` method it work fine, but when `$formulation` string too long, the server reported that Request-URI Too Large.

Anybody know this problem or any solution that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing looks a bit complex, try simply this:

```
<textarea name="argument" id="argumentId" rows="10" cols="50" value="<?php echo $formulation; ?>"></textarea>
```

This puts your string directly into the `textarea value`, without trying to use it as a parameter for your function.

AND reason why your you get nothing from `$formulation` when you use it as a paramter for your function is because your code should be like so:

```
echo "<script>insertFormulationToTextErea(".$formulation.")</script>";
```

Though I highly advise you to avoid coding like that..

Comment: Now it work. Thank you... php code should be between tags: `<textarea name="argument" id="argumentId" rows="10" cols="50""><?php echo $formulation; ?></textarea>`

Comment: No problem, good luck. :) Glad I could help. Keep in mind though, textarea value and textarea innerHTML are two different things.